# integrate firestore from v8 to v9

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, reactfire

I am looking to retrieve my sub collection "messages" within the "channels" collection and display them on my chat page. I tried different tactics like useEffect but with no result.

How would I change this line of code from v8 to v9?:

```
const [messages] = useCollection(
channelId &&
    db
.doc(channelId)
.collection("messages")
.orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
  );
```

Message display section:

```
<div>
  {messages?.docs.map((doc) => {
 const { message, timestamp, name, photoURL, email } = doc.data();
 return (
 <Message
          key={doc.id}
          id={doc.id}
          message={message}
          timestamp={timestamp}
          name={name}
          email={email}
          photoURL={photoURL}
        />
 );
 })}
</div>
```

I am able to send message to firestore, but getting it to display has been a problem. Everytime I map through messages, my app turn blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to retrieve the data once you do not need a useEffect hook.

Perform the query as follows:

```js
    const collectionRef = query(
        collection(db, `channels/${channelId}/messages`),
        orderBy("timestamp", "asc"));
    
    const messageDocs = await collectionRef.get() // this is only the docs
    
    // to get the doc data you will need to map each doc to its data
    
    const messageDocsData = messageDocs.map((doc) => doc.data())
```

If you want your data to change on the UI as the database is updated you will need useEffect:

```js
    const [messageDocsData, setMessageDocsData] = useState([]);

    const collectionRef = query(
        collection(db, `channels/${channelId}/messages`),
        orderBy("timestamp", "asc"));

    useEffect(() => {
       const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collectionRef, (querySnapshot) =>
      setMessageDocsData(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
    );

    return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);
    
   // messageDocsData will now always have the latest snapshot of the documents
```